# Switch the translated term

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-translate

I have an Ionic Multilingual App in wich there's a select.
One of the select options disable some page elements. So far so good.

But one of the elements has to change its text supplied by the translation.

**SELECTED OPTION: A ->**

{{"1ST_TERM" | translate}}

**SELECTED OPTION: B ->**

{{"2ND_TERM" | translate}}

My code for the select is:

```
<select id="select" 
ng-model="selOption" 
ng-change="selectUpdate(selOption)">
     <option value="A">SICLANO</option>
     <option value="B">BELTRANO</option>
</select>

<p id="text">CORRECT TRANSLATED TERM</p>

$scope.selectUpdate= function(selOption){
   switch (selOption){
     case 'A':
             //CHANGE #text TO TRANSLATED TERM 1ST_TERM 
     case 'B':
             //CHANGE #text TO TRANSLATED TERM 2ND_TERM
   };
};
```

Can you guys help?

Comment: did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40302890/2545680) help?

Comment: Hi @Maximus, sorry I'm AFK. Saw the answer but didn't tested yet xD

Comment: no problem, will wait for you feedback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `$translate` service and use to get translation:

```
$scope.selectUpdate= function(selOption){
   switch (selOption){
     case 'A':
             $translate(selOption).then(function (translated) {
                $scope.text = translated;
             }
   };
};
```

To show it, add interpolation to `p` tag:

```
<p id="text">{{text}}</p>
```